# How to find A(i, d)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, limits-and-convergence, digits

Let $s(n)$ denote the digit sum of a natural number $n$. For $i, d\in \mathbb{N}$ define $$A(i, d) = \limsup_{m\to \infty}\frac{|\{n\leq m | s(n)\equiv i\mod d\}|}{m}.$$ Compute $A(i, d)$ for all $i, d$.

Comment: The limit exists and equals $1/d$. That and much more is covered in [this thesis](https://dmg.tuwien.ac.at/drmota/morgenbesserda.pdf).

Comment: You find aid on MO.

Comment: @Wojowu Please turn your comment into an answer so that this question can be closed.